# Query database for articles, filtering by tag

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, database, tags, com-content

I can use this to get published articles from the database:

```
function queryDatabase_Posts($select, $limit) {
    // Database connection and query object.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    // Select.
    $query->select($select);
    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
    // Published posts only.
    $query->where($db->quoteName('state') . ' = 1'); 
    // Order by the date they are published.
    $query->order('publish_up DESC');
    // Set and fetch.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    return $db->loadAssocList();     
}
```

but according to [this overview](https://docs.joomla.org/Tables/content) of the `#__content` table tags are apparently kept in a different table.

How can I query that table? What is it called, what's inside? Is there documentation on that?

Ultimately I want to query the database for posts that have a certain tag of which I have the name. So I would need to query the tag table for the ID.

Answer (score 3):

You could **[Join](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Selecting_Records_from_Multiple_Tables)** the `#__content` table with the one of the `#__contentitem_tag_map`, which is the table that stores the many-to-many relationships among the various content items and the tags:

```
$query->join('INNER', '#__contentitem_tag_map AS tags ON `tags`.`content_item_id` = `#__content`.`id`');
```

Then in your query you can filter the content items with a where:

```
$query->where('(tags.tag_id = '. $yourTag .') AND `tags`.`type_id` = 1');
```

- In your script, pass your desired tag to the `$yourTag` variable.
- The `tags.type_id = 1` is the type for the tags associated with articles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you happen to know where the tags are stored? I am trying to access all tags there are - so no connection to any article needs to be given.

Comment: Nevermind, connecting to the database and looking at the tables showed me it's just #__tags...